# What causes the 'Inconsistent Accesibility' error in the follow code?

Tags: c#

The error:

> Error 1   Inconsistent accessibility: field type
>   `'System.Collections.Generic.List<Lines>'` is less accessible than field
>   `'Star.lines'`    J:\Documenting\Universiteit Utrecht - Game
>   Technology\Modelleren en Systeem
>   Ontwikkeling\Assignment4\ShapeDrawing\ShapeDrawing\Star.cs    15  24  ShapeDrawing

The Code that causes the error:

```
public class Star : Shape
{

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    public List<Lines> lines; // TODO: Ask explanation for cause of error. 

    public Star (int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public override void CalculateGeometry()
    {
        lines = new List<Lines>();

        int numPoints = 5;
        Point[] pts = new Point[numPoints];
        double rx = width / 2;
        double ry = height / 2;
        double cx = x + rx;
        double cy = y + ry;

        double theta = -Math.PI / 2;
        double dtheta = 4 * Math.PI / numPoints;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < numPoints; i++)
        {
            pts[i] = new Point(
                Convert.ToInt32(cx + rx * Math.Cos(theta)),
                Convert.ToInt32(cy + ry * Math.Sin(theta)));
            theta += dtheta;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < numPoints; i++)
        {
            lines.Add(new Lines(pts[i].X,
                                pts[i].Y,
                                pts[(i + 1) % numPoints].X,
                                pts[(i + 1) % numPoints].Y));
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried looking into the causes of the error. It seems to be caused by a public field being used from a public class. In this case it seems like both the method and the field are public, so I am not sure what the problem is.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: You haven't shown the declaration of `Lines`, but I suspect that's an `internal` class, so you can't use it in a public field. As an aside, I'd strongly encourage you not to use public fields anyway.

Comment: Yeah, your most likely have this:  protected class Lines (or something less accessible than public, which would be internal, protected or private).  Change that to public class Lines.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot. Somehow I missed that every time. Very much appreciated. Sorry for posting a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are exposing a type on a class then the type must be at least as accessible as the class.

In your case, `Star` and `CalculateGeometry` are `public`, so `Lines`, as it's exposed on a public method, must also be public.

You can either make it public, or reduce the accessibility of the class to be equal or less than the `Lines` class.

`Lines` is probably `internal`, as that's the default if you don't add a access modifier.

From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx):

- `public`

  - Access is not restricted.
- `protected`

  - Access is limited to the containing class or types derived from the containing class.
- `internal`

  - Access is limited to the current assembly.
- `protected internal`

  - Access is limited to the current assembly or types derived from the containing class.
- `private`

  - Access is limited to the containing type.

Answer (score 0):

**public** `class Star`

Your `Lines` class is less accessible than `Star`.

Change the access of `Lines` to **public**.